Why am I getting "SYNC_SERVICE_START_FAILED ERROR 20000" in GridDB when starting the synchronization service?
I'm using GridDB to manage a distributed database cluster, and I recently encountered the following error when attempting to start the synchronization service:
from griddb_python import StoreFactory, GSException

def start_sync_service():
    try:
        # Connect to GridDB cluster
        factory = StoreFactory.get_default()
        gridstore = factory.get_store({
            "host": "239.0.0.1",
            "port": 41999,
            "cluster_name": "defaultCluster",
            "username": "admin",
            "password": "admin"
        })

        # Retrieve container
        container = gridstore.get_container("containerName")
        if container is None:
            raise Exception("Container not found")

        # Simulate data synchronization across nodes
        row = container.get(1)
        print(f"Data retrieved: {row}")

        # Perform a write operation to trigger synchronization
        container.put(2, {"id": 2, "value": "syncTest"})
        print("Data synchronized across cluster")

    except GSException as e:
        print(f"Sync service failed to start: {e.what()}")
        raise

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_sync_service()

I connect to the GridDB cluster and attempt to retrieve and update data on a container.
The goal is to start the synchronization service between nodes, but the process fails with the SYNC_SERVICE_START_FAILED ERROR 20000.
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04
Python Version: 3.8
GridDB Version: 4.5
Cluster Size: 5 nodes
System Memory: 8GB per node
I’m looking for guidance on:
How to check if the memory is indeed insufficient and causing the SYNC_SERVICE_START_FAILED ERROR 20000.
Best practices for ensuring sufficient memory for synchronization services in a GridDB cluster.
Steps I can take to adjust memory configurations or other system settings to avoid this issue.
